# How to get value before comma in the column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I have column which has values like so `foo,bar` in mySql Database.
I would like to take out only the `foo` and discard the rest of the data after comma. How do I get that?

Comment: Don't store data as comma separated items.

Comment: Yea I know. I am correcting the garbage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `substring_index()`:

```
select substring_index(col, ',', 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use Split() function.**

**Example:**

```
var original_Data = foo,bar ;

var required_Data = original_Data.Split(',')[0];

this will result required_Data = foo;

If you want a "bar" then
var required_Data = original_Data.Split(',')[1];

this will result required_Data = bar;
```